# Forms validation condition With react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, jsx

I'm learning reactjs and I have a problem with the validation in forms
so I want to have a condition if the user don't enter his name a message 'empty field' appear

else alert hello 'his name' appears

**My code**

```
import React ,{Component} from 'react';
class Formular extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state={
          nom:'',
          prenom:'',
          email:'',
          password:'',
          error:false,
          NameErr:''
      }
      
    }
    
    handleValidation() {
         if (this.state.nom =='')
         { this.state.error=true
           this.state.NameErr='empty field'
            //console.log( this.state.NameErr)
            return(
                this.state.NameErr
            )
        }
    }
    
    handleClick(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        let error = this.handleValidation()
        if (!error)  
        { 
            alert('hello '+ this.state.nom)
        } 
    }
 

    render() {
       /*  console.log('nom',this.state.nom)
        console.log('prenom',this.state.prenom) */
        return (
        <div >
            <div className="form__group field">
                <input type="input" className="form__field" 
                placeholder="Name" name="name" id='name' 
                required size='100' value={this.state.nom}  
                onChange={(event)=>this.setState({nom:event.target.value})} />
                <label for="name" className="form__label">Name</label>
            </div>

            <div className='alert'> {this.state.NameErr}  </div>
             
export default Formular
```

Answer (score 2):

You must not change the state by force

like this

```
this.state.NameErr='empty field'
this.state.error=true
```

You need to use `setState`

like this example

```
this.setState({NameErr:'empty field',error:true})
```

then you can in render method

```
{ this.state.error && <div className='alert'> {this.state.NameErr}</div>}
```

Thus the element will only be displayed if there is an error

Comment: i have changed my code to this 
this.setState({NameErr:'empty field',error:true})
but the alert 'hello ' appear even if my field is empty

Comment: i even afer that when i enter any string in the field name the message ''empty field'' does not disapear

Comment: how can i have the message 'empty field ' only when the user don't enter any thing ?

Comment: also the message alert it apear even the field is empty

Comment: Because   is in condition ``if (this.state.nom =='')``

Answer (score 2):

Mutation of state isn't correct, always mutate state using setState()

```
this.setState({NameErr:'empty field', error: true})
```

jsx

```
{this.state.error && <div className='alert'> {this.state.NameErr}  </div>}
```

Comment: i have changed my code to this this.setState({NameErr:'empty field',error:true}) but the alert 'hello ' appear even if my field is empty even 
 
i even after that when i enter any string in the field name the message ''empty field'' does not disappear
how can i have the message 'empty field ' only when the user don't enter any thing ?
also the message alert it appear even the field is empty

Answer (score 1):

First, you should wrap your input in form tag instead simply div.
Next use event `onSubmit` on your form to trigger submission of the form.

Create un method to check if your value is not empty, then do what you want

```
render () {

  return <form onSubmit={handleClick}>
    <div className="form__group field">
      <input 
        id='name' name="name"  type="text" 
        className="form__field" 
        size='100' required 
        placeholder="Name" value={this.state.nom}
        onChange={(event)=>this.setState({nom:event.target.value})} 
      />
      <label for="name" className="form__label">Name</label>
    </div>;

    <div className='alert'> {this.state.NameErr}  </div>
  </form>;
}
```

NT: type attribute of input should be "text" and not "input"

EDIT: Like said other guys, change also your changing state.